# Zurb Foundation dropdown menu isn't working with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, zurb-foundation, meteorite, iron-router

I'm trying to use a dropdown menu with Meteor, but it's now working. I don't know if it's related with the packages that I have installed:

https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/zurb-foundation

https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/iron-router

https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/accounts-entry

https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/iron-router-progress

Here is the dropdown example:

```
<section class="top-bar-section">
        <ul class="right">
          <li class="has-dropdown">
            <a href="#">user</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
            </ul>
          <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
```

What might be the problem? The console prints this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'is_hover' of undefined

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing any code.

Comment: I already updated the question with the code. I tested the code without meteor and it works well.

Comment: are you sure you are following the foundation 5.0 examples/documentation? your html looks very different from the examples I see here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html

Answer (score 2):

you can do $('document').foundation('reflow') on rendered template like here: [zf5.meteor.com](http://zf5.meteor.com)

Comment: This seems to work. Specifically: $(document).foundation('topbar', 'reflow');

Answer (score 0):

This works great using the zurb-foundation package you linked to:

```html
  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="right">
      <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-dropdown="drop1">user</a>
        <ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried the code you suggested but it doesn't work. The console prints this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'is_hover' of undefined

Comment: sounds like there is something else going wrong in your project. If you create a new meteor project, add the zurb-foundation package and then copy this code into the .html file it should work -- at least it did for me.

Comment: It could be a problem related with the other packages?

Comment: perhaps the easiest way to find out would be to create a new project, then add this code, and then add the packages one by one and see when you get the error. This should be very quick.